# Weird SearchLogic error (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

My search form is triggering this.

```
undefined method `id_like_before_type_cast' for #<Class:0xb5ffff68>
```

Here's the line from the form:

```
<%= f.text_field :id_like %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem on my machine. I believe the problem resulted from attempting to upgrade from Rails 2.3.9 to Rails 2.3.12, then backing back down to 2.3.9. I did this without deleting my vendor/rails directory and it looks like some files from 2.3.12 got left behind.

The solution was to delete the vendor/rails directory, then reinstall (and freeze) Rails 2.3.9.